# Bootstrap 3: How to create responsive, square .thumbnail divs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created a grid of images using Bootstrap 3's .thumbnail class. Everything seems to be working great with regards to the images resizing, and the columns changing depending on the window size. The only problem is the images are all different sizes, and both portrait/landscape orientation. This causes awkward breaks and "pile-ups" with the thumbnail divs…

[image: This is what I currently have]

I was hoping to find a way to create a grid of SQUARE responsive divs using the .thumbnail class. So in other words, the width determined by Bootstrap would be mirrored in the div's height. E.g. the thumbnail image is scaled to 220px so the height of the div containing it would be set to 220px as well (and the thumbnail image inside scales up to 100% of eight the height or width, depending on orientation). Sort of like this:

[image: This is what I'm hoping to achieve]

Here is the basic code I'm using:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <a href="<?php echo dirname($image->url()); ?>/detail/<?php echo $image->name() ?>-detail.jpg" class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="group"><img src="<?php echo $image->url() ?>"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks so much for any help you might be able to offer. I'm also open to suggestions for other approaches. I even tried using jquery Isotope's masonry setting to solve the pile up problem but couldn't get it to work :(

Answer (score 4):

You could try a CSS only approach like this this..

http://bootply.com/85737

However, this is not cross-browser compatible so you still may want to use the Isotope plugin. Here is a working example that uses Isotope + Bootstrap..

http://bootply.com/61482

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm going to have to go with Isotope. I haven't been able to get it to work with my code yet, but I'll keep at it. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

I have created a small plugin for bootstrap, called bootstrap-grid-h. You can try using it. It is css only solution. You can find it here: [bootstrap-grid-h](https://github.com/A0dh/bootstrap-grid-h)

Comment: I checked this out, and it seems to be working, but I want my square divs to have child divs with a shaded background, so I had to override your default 8px padding. Just adding `.h-content` alone didn't work because the `.h>div` rule overrides the less specific `.h-content`. So I had to add a more specific rule `.h>div.h-content {padding:0px}`

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying it out. You actually can change it in _vars.scss, as by default it takes $grid-gutter-width / 2, which is a default padding for bootstrap grid. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

For something like this I would recommend using masonry which will give you a pinterest effect where images will fit in a block style without breaks.

such as: http://osvaldas.info/responsive-jquery-masonry-or-pinterest-style-layout

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I think you are right. I am going to keep trying to get Isotope to work. I think it's conflicting with something in my code… Again, thank you!