# HTML tags getting overlapped in a bootstrap 3 Thumbnail class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created Bootstrap thumbnails as link images to other parts of a web application. Used [Bootstrap 3 square tile display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21318704/bootstrap-3-square-tile-display) to create my thumbnails with an `<a>` tag incorporated inside the thumbnail. Trying to add additional information using `<p>` inside the thumbnail `<div>`. The `<p>` tags are overlapping each element. For example the last `<p>` tag overlaps any tag before it. (This is  only true when I add the class "Thumbnail" to the `<p>` tags. Tried various ways to solve this, but have not been able to come up with a solution. Please see code below or at http://www.bootply.com/boXJrupqT0  (You will see the overlapping text at the very bottom of the Thumbnail)

My goal: To get the `<a>` and two `<p>` tags viewable on the same `<div>` while text wrapping (if needed). Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

HTML:

```
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 capabilitiesTiles">
        <div class="squareThumbnails"></div>
        <a href="#x" class="thumbnail purple">Test A</a>
        <p>Dkadlgjaklsgjasdglajdslkgjaklsjg</p>
        <p>agdagsdvasbaerasdhadgasdgasdhasdhadhasdhahasha</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 capabilitiesTiles">
        <div class="squareThumbnails"></div>
        <a href="#x" class="thumbnail purple">Test B</a>
        <p>Dkadlgjaklsgjasdglajdslkgjaklsjg</p>
        <p>agdagsdvasbaerasdhadgasdgasdhasdhadhasdhahasha</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 capabilitiesTiles">
        <div class="squareThumbnails"></div>
        <a href="#x" class="thumbnail purple">Test C</a>
        <p>Dkadlgjaklsgjasdglajdslkgjaklsjg</p>
        <p>agdagsdvasbaerasdhadgasdgasdhasdhadhasdhahasha</p>
   </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

.squareThumbnails {
    margin-top: 100%;
}
.thumbnail {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 15px;
    right: 0;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:calc(50% - 110px);
}

.capabilitiesTiles {
    margin: 0px 10px -15px 65px;
}

.row .thumbnail {
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's because your thumbnails have `position:absolute`
Just add `height` attribute to your thumbnail class [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ebrx4sem/6/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried adding a thumbnail class to the first '<p>' tag in Test A thumbnail and it actually just created a new thumbnail underneath it. What I am trying to achieve is by having the "a" and two "p" tags inside the dame thumbnail. How would I be able to achieve that? Thank you