# how to show the result in thumbnail gridview like pininterest using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I show the result in my webpage like pininterest thumnail gridview and dynamically column and rows creation?

Below code is showing thumbnails but all results are in different row and making the page too long, i want them to use full page and scroll if require.

```
     <div id="resultBox" class="span6">

<!--<div class="container">-->
    <div class="row-fluid">
         <ul ng-repeat="place in allresultsfinal.placeList" class="thumbnails">
            <li class="span4">
                <div class="thumbnail" style="padding: 0">
                    <div style="padding:4px">
                        <img alt="300x200" style="width: 100%" src="/ngdemo/img/hotelDemo.JPG">
                    </div>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h2><b>{{ place.name }}</b></h2>
                        <p>Company description</p>
                        <p><i class="icon icon-map-marker"></i> {{ place.formattedAddress }} </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer" style="text-align: left">
                        <div class="progress">
                            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
                                <span class="sr-only">Pros:</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4"><b>05 KM</b><br/><small>Distance</small></div>
                            <div class="col-md-4"><b>4</b><br/><small>Rating</small></div>
                            <div class="col-md-4"><b>28</b><br/><small>Reviews</small></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you should adjust classes within thumbnail.  Modal footer probably shouldn't be in there. http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504755/bootstrap-3-how-to-create-responsive-square-thumbnail-divs?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 gallery">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.gallery img {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N7mYY/